# How to get the settings file saved to released folder in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I built a small C# windows application in VS 10.0. I want to use the released exe file to be called from some other hosting application. In the settings I added a connection string, and I want the settings file to be released as well, so that when I change the connection string (to point for the test database for example) the released application will respond accordingly.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need this:

```
string conn = Properties.Settings.Default.Connection_String;
```

Just replace Connection_String with the name you've set and you're good to go.

Comment: Actually coding part is done. I could access the connection string from within the code using the statement you mentioned. My question is how to publish the settings file, as XML for example, so that we can change the connection string from within that file